# How do I use django_facebook to authorize and authenticate a user?

Tags: python, django, django-facebook

I am having a hard time understanding the authentication flow of django_facebook. If I have a native android app do I use my app id and app secret in the 'settings.py' or do I use the app id and secret in my native app to get the api key?

Comment: you need to create app in developers.facebook.com and it gives you facebook_app_id and app_secret. After that you should use it at setting .py not your android app id and secret... for more http://django-facebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: How about when I want to login with android. The chapter on mobile does not explain what I am supposed to do with the api key I get from there. Is it the same as if I was using the Java script sdk?